# Make an editable table and save to a database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that I get from my MySQL base using ajax. The answer from ajax makes the table in a DIV wrapper.

Now I need to edit this table and if it is needed to save it, but I've got several problems.

My plan was to make a `$('td').click()` append an input and after pressing enter or clicking anywhere the input should be hidden and the clear TD with new value should appear. After that I presss the UPDATE button and save my row to DB.
But my JavaScript skills are not so good and I failed even with 100 of examples.

Here is my code:

```
$('#load').click(function() {
  //the load button - gets the table from DB  
  //here I get some data from the website filter.
  var data = new webmaster(pid, name, email, skype, web, current_offer, lookingfor_offer, anwsered, comment);
  data = JSON.stringify(data);

  $('#aw-wrapper').empty();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "data": data
    },
    url: "inc/load-web.php",
    success: function(anwser) {
      $('#aw-wrapper').html(anwser);
      TableEdit();
    }

  });

});

function TableEdit() {

  if (i) {
    $('td').click(function() {

      this.onclick = null;
      var td_value = $(this).html();
      var input_field = '<input type="text" id="edit" value="' + td_value + '" />'
      $(this).empty().append(input_field);
      $('input').focus();
      i = 0;
    });
  }
}
```

But it doesnot work at all. I got many clicks on td instead of one. Maybe I am doing it wrong and it can be realized easier?

Comment: You could also look into a library like [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com).

Comment: What's being returned from your php file? An HTML `table` with data from the database?

Comment: Yes a HTML TABLE with data from database! It is so hard to do so I should use a lb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see where i is defined. I changed your function to look like this:

```
function TableEdit() {
var i = 1;

$('td').click(function() {
        if (i) {
    this.onclick = null;
    var td_value = $(this).html();
    var input_field = '<input type="text" id="edit" value="' + td_value + '" />'
    $(this).empty().append(input_field);
    $('input').focus();
    i = 0;
    }

});
}
```

if I understand what you want i believe it gives the desired result, however, this is how i would implement this

```
function TableEdit() {


$('td').click(function() {


    var td_value = $(this).html();
    var input_field = '<input type="text" id="edit" value="' + td_value + '" />'
    $(this).empty().append(input_field);
    $('input').focus();

    $('td').off('click');

    $(this).find('input').blur(function(){
        var new_text = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().html(new_text);
        TableEdit();
    })

});
}
```

updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vf2L78p8/2/

Comment: no - it doesnot. Everytime i = 1 so every click will make a new input

Comment: here is a fiddle i created https://jsfiddle.net/vf2L78p8/  does that do what you are looking for?

Comment: it is a part of what I need. But thank you. Why does the same code in fiddle work fine and in my js document doesnot work? My code makes a lot of inputs

Comment: Did you also move the if statement to be in the click() function? when the if statement was outside I was getting the error you were talking about

Comment: oh. Thanks a lot. I found a way to do it shorter: $(this).unbind('click'); May be you know  howto get the blur event? I need to make input again to td when the input looses the focus but I dont know how to do this